# Pie hidden serie: datalabels not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When i hide a pie series, its datalabels aren't dissappearing.

```
var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
        $button.html('Show series');
    } else {
        series.show();
        $button.html('Hide series');
    }
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ABydq/)

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in high charts, every other chart type that I tested hid the datalabels. Would you be able to use another chart type for your data?

Comment: Created at ticket here if you want to follow up on it.   https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2315

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure it was a bug, and not an oversight of mine. Thanks for reporting, I will follow it.